# How to escape strings in Laravel 5.4 Markdown mails?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

Laravel 5.4 has a new feature. You can use Markdown in mail templates.

Here is my mail blade template:

```
# Message for you!

Hello {{ $user->name }},

@foreach($messages as $message)
{{ $message->text }}
@endforeach

Greetings
```

My problem is: The first character of `$message->text` can be a **#** (*number sign or hash*), so the String is parsed as a headline...

**Update:**

You can escape all markdown characters with **\** (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198231)

I've tried to escape all chars with this code:

```
$text = str_replace(
    ['\\', '`', '*', '_', '{', '}', '[', ']', '(', ')', '#', '+', '-', '.', '!'],
    ['\\\\', '\`', '\*', '\_', '\{', '\}', '\[', '\]', '\(', '\)', '\#', '\+', '\-', '\.', '\!'],
    $text
);
```

But i think it's not the recommended way...

How can i escape the string?

Greetings

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution!
I think you can use this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i found my solution! You have to create a new mail component...

At first you must publish the email components from laravel with `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#customizing-the-components). Now you have a `vendor` folder in your `resources/views`.

Go into `resources/views/mail/html` and create a new `.blade.php` file. My file looks like this:

```
<table class="notification" align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="notification-meta">
            {{ $time }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="notification-content">
            {{ $slot }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You must create the same file under `resources/views/markdown/html` for the plain text mails.

If you look into `resources/views/mail/html/footer.blade.php` you can see the following function in the template:

```
{{ Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::parse($slot) }}
```

This function parse markdown to html. I don't use the function in my template.

Now i can use my component in the mail like:

```
# Message for you!

Hello {{ $user->name }},

@component('mail::notification', ['time' => '06.02.2017' ])
{{ $text }}
@endcomponent

Greetings
```

And the `$text` will not being parsed from markdown to html :)

Comment: This did not work for my setup in Laravel8.x. Passing the string as variable to a (sub-)template will still trigger parsing on a string like `U*jE+X6D(B7*4}fn` (replace `*...*` with `<em>...</em>`.
`Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::parse()` is just an explicit markdown parsing command to assure parsing, even when is switched off for your message.

`addcslashes()` was my saviour

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to escape the first character in blade.

A possible way to work around this could be to change the '#' with the html number `&#35;`

In your controller you could check if the message starts with an # and replace it with `&#35;`

```
function replaceFirstChar($message)
{
    if ($message[0] == "#") {
        $new_message = '&#35' . substr($message, 1);
        return $new_message;
    } else {
        return $message;
    }
}
```

I think this should work.

**UPDATE**

```
addcslashes($str , '\ `*[]()#+-.!');
```

This should do the trick. (possible that you need to add some extra characters)

Comment: ok, thanks, this is a simple solution, but i must escape all markdown characters at any position of the string.

I thought there is a function or a blade syntax to avoid parsing markdown characters.

Comment: I updated the answer. I think this is what you need.